# Could we design a Turing machine that output every bit of $\pi$ one after another correctly with limited tape length?

Tags: computability, turing-machines

Could we design a Turing machine that output every bit of $\pi$ one after another correctly?

I think we have computer programs that calculate the value of $\pi$ day after day, and thus it's viable.

Could we do that if the Turing machine has a limited tape length?

Comment: As for capability, yes we could. As for tape length I don't think so unless you compute up to some certain number of digits.

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "output every bit of $\pi$ one after another"? There are infinitely many such bits so you can never output _every_ one of them. And what do you mean by the machine having limited tape length? If it has limited tape length, it only has room to output that many bits. Do you mean limited working space? Ultimately, though, the answer to your question is, "Yes. $\pi$ is a [computable number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number)."

Answer (score 4):

If by "limited tape length", you mean having a finite amount of memory, then the answer is "no".  With a finite amount of memory, the Turing machine as a whole can be modeled as a finite state machine.  A finite state machine that doesn't terminate must eventually repeat a state and thus fall into a loop. Therefore, the output of any such machine must correspond to the binary expansion of a rational number. The binary expansion of any irrational number whatsoever will require an unbounded amount of state.

Answer (score 2):

As $\pi$ is a transcendental (yet computable) number, all algorithms that calculate its digits will have to rely on approximation strategies that entail the instantaneous use of increasingly large numbers.

If there was a limit to these quantities, it wouldn't be possible to continue representing digits with ever greater precision, and repetitive patterns (that we know do not exist) would necessarily emerge in the execution of any deterministic algorithm.